# What happens to Spring bean after ApplicationContext is shutdown

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

Suppose I have a normal application in which I am creating a Spring application context using `ApplicationContext applicationContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("bean.xml");`

Now, suppose in this bean.xml  there is bean definition for a Spring bean `Bean1`, so when I will create the application context then Spring container will instantiate and initialize an object for this `Bean1`.

And then I have a non-Spring object holding a reference to the object of this Spring bean `Bean1`.

Now, lets say I shutdown the application context using `((ConfigurableApplicationContext)appCtx).close();`.

Now my questions are:

1. What will happen to the object this Spring bean `Bean1`, will it be garbage collected as soon as Spring's ApplicationContext is shutdown?
2. Since I am holding a reference to the object of this Spring bean `Bean1`, will I still have this object or will object reference variable pointing to this will become NULL?

Comment: I think the only issue is that is your Bean1 object has a close method, it will get called when you close the application context.  I do not think closing the application forces GC of specific objects (I think its not even possible as this is under the control of the JVM)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ApplicationContext` uses `HashMap` under the hood for storing beans and if you call `close()` on it, its going to call `clear()` method on these `HashMap`s.
As you know when we call `clear()` method on `HashMap`, it's only assigns the `null` to map `Entries` so if there is another object that references to those objects, they will survive.

So your questions:

1. No, Because there is another reference to `Bean1`
2. You still have it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it will not be null.

I have an interface Coach, and class that implements it TrackCoach, which has a method called

`getDailyWorkout();`

I am doing a basic calling of a bean from the container using `getBean()`

Here is a main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    //load spring configuration file
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    // retrieve bean from spring container
    Coach theCoach = context.getBean("myCoach", Coach.class);
    //call methods on bean
    System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyWorkout());
    Object o = new Object();
    o = theCoach;
    System.out.println("this is Object before closing> "+o);
    //close context
    System.out.println("Closing context");
    context.close();
    System.out.println("After closing context");
    System.out.println("this is a regular usage of bean reference> "+theCoach.getDailyWorkout());
    System.out.println("this is Object AFTER closing> "+o);
    Coach c = (Coach) o;
    
    System.out.println("this is AFTER CASTING> "+c.getDailyWorkout());

}
```

And the output is the following

```
    Jun 09, 2022 6:36:00 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6d9c638: startup date [Thu Jun 09 18:36:00 CEST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 09, 2022 6:36:00 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
    Run for 20 min 
    this is Object before closing> com.juradent.springdemo.TrackCoach@69b0fd6f
    Closing context
    Jun 09, 2022 6:36:01 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
    INFO: Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6d9c638: startup date [Thu Jun 09 18:36:00 CEST 2022]; root of context hierarchy
    After closing context
    this is a regular usage of bean reference> Run for 20 min
    this is Object AFTER closing> com.juradent.springdemo.TrackCoach@69b0fd6f
    this is AFTER CASTING> Run for 20 min
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Your answer was also equally good.